# MySQL friends table query

Tags: mysql

I have a friends table set up with columns like this:

```
requester_user_id //the user initiating the request
requested_user_id //the user responding to the request
established //bool, true is 'these two are friends'
```

I have some other columns, but they are not important for this question.

What I need is a query that will get a list of all of your friend IDs. The thing is, your ID might be in requester OR requested, depending on who initiated the request.

I feel like there has got to be a simple way, but I can not figure it out without doing multiple `if`s.

Comment: `select requester_user_id from yourTable where established=true` isn't this working ?

Comment: Thing is I need requester OR requested, whichever isn't me :)  I know my id.  I need the other ID.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
select distinct 
       case requester_user_id 
            when @myid then requested_user_id 
            else requester_user_id 
       end id
from friends
where @myid in (requester_user_id, requested_user_id)
```

Comment: This looks like it would work!  I wasn't aware of case statements in MySQL :D  I will try as soon as I have the chance to.  Thanks, I'll let you know how ti works out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct id from (
SELECT requested_user_id as id FROM friends where requester_user_id = @myid
UNION
SELECT requester_user_id as id FROM friends where requested_user_id = @myid
)
```

Comment: Thing is I just want a list of the other people's IDs, not mine.

Comment: @J.P.: This will return *other* people's IDs - it's a union of request**er**s when request**ed** matches \@myid, and vice versa.